# What is the difference between these two SQL function?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I've been recently solving a SQL problem on hackerrank.com([LINK](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-1/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) to the problem) and I found out that two exactly(as far as I know) same code give different outputs.

The input table is this. The table name is 'bst'.

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| N | Integer |
| P | Integer |

| N | P |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 4 | 15 |
| 8 | 9 |
| 10 | 9 |
| 12 | 13 |
| 14 | 13 |
| 9 | 11 |
| 13 | 11 |
| 11 | 15 |
| 15 | Null |

It is a simple table with two columns named 'N' and 'P'. I had to define whether each 'N' is a 'root' or 'leaf' or 'inner' node. So I made this query as an answer to this problem. I wrote it in MySQL.

```
SELECT N,
CASE 
    WHEN P IS NOT Null AND N NOT IN (SELECT P FROM bst) THEN 'Leaf'
    WHEN P IS Null AND N IN (SELECT P FROM bst) THEN 'Root'
    ELSE 'Inner'
END
FROM bst
ORDER BY N;
```

This did not give me any 'leaf' node and it only printed out 'inner' or 'root'. Following is the result.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Inner |
| 2 | Inner |
| 3 | Inner |
| 4 | Inner |
| 5 | Inner |
| 6 | Inner |
| 7 | Inner |
| 8 | Inner |
| 9 | Inner |
| 10 | Inner |
| 11 | Inner |
| 12 | Inner |
| 13 | Inner |
| 14 | Inner |
| 15 | Root |

But there was nothing wrong with my logic so as I was troubleshooting this and that, I found out that if I just change '(SELECT P FROM bst)' part into actual row values like '(2,2,6,6,4,4,15,9,9,13,13,11,11,15)' only for conditions regarding 'leaf', it gives me the right answer. The code is as follows. (It is identical to the code above but only the call for second WHEN clause is different.)

```
SELECT N,
CASE 
    WHEN P IS NOT Null AND N NOT IN (2,2,6,6,4,4,15,9,9,13,13,11,11,15) THEN 'Leaf'
    WHEN P IS Null AND N IN (SELECT P FROM bst) THEN 'Root'
    ELSE 'Inner'
END
FROM bst
ORDER BY N;
```

This gave me the following result and this is the right answer for the problem.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Leaf |
| 2 | Inner |
| 3 | Leaf |
| 4 | Inner |
| 5 | Leaf |
| 6 | Inner |
| 7 | Leaf |
| 8 | Leaf |
| 9 | Inner |
| 10 | Leaf |
| 11 | Inner |
| 12 | Leaf |
| 13 | Inner |
| 14 | Leaf |
| 15 | Root |

I couldn't find the difference between 'SELECT P FROM bst' and just the list of the values from column P. Is it something to do with setting alias? If that was the case, then why is it okay to use it in the condition for 'root'? Please help me out.

Comment: Please post data as text not images.

Comment: @Serg Thank you for letting me know. I changed all of them into texts.

Comment: Your second query is doing `SELECT P FROM base WHERE P is not null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.

The problem with
'SELECT P FROM bst'
clause was that it has a null value in its output(15th row). So when there is a null value in the condition, it automatically gave out 'false' and did not compare them to actual non-null values.
So, the correct code using nested sentence should be:

```
SELECT N,
CASE 
    WHEN P IS NOT Null AND N NOT IN (SELECT P FROM bst WHERE P IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Leaf'
    WHEN P IS Null AND N IN (SELECT P FROM bst) THEN 'Root'
    ELSE 'Inner'
END
FROM bst
ORDER BY N;
```

I added 'WHERE P IS NOT NULL' in the sentence for finding 'Leaf'. This code gives out the right answer.

Comment: This is exactly why we prefer NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN.  `.. AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bst b2 WHERE b2.P = bst.N) ..`

Answer (score 0):

> WHEN P IS NOT Null AND NOT N IN (SELECT P FROM bst) THEN 'Leaf'

```
SELECT N,
CASE 
    WHEN P IS NOT Null AND NOT N IN (SELECT P FROM bst) THEN 'Leaf'
    WHEN P IS Null AND N IN (SELECT P FROM bst) THEN 'Root'
    ELSE 'Inner'
END
FROM bst
ORDER BY N;
```

Comment: Could you add some info on how providing some query solves the difference between two other queries ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this gives out the exactly same result as the first query which outputs the wrong answer. I guess changing the place of 'NOT' did not affect the code.